# Flipping Book HTML5 flipbook hosted in SharePoin

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sharepoint, cewp

I have used the publication software FlippingBook and created an html5 complaint website that will load the book.  This is hosted on an iis server and when I navigate to the url it looks great.  So in SharePoint I have created a web part page and put a content editor web part in and tied it to something like this:

content.txt

When I navigate to the sharepoint page containing the web part you can see the flipping book but all of the JS has been stripped and it only shows the "basic HTML" version of the web site.  Does anyone have any experience in SharePoint with this?

Comment: What version of SharePoint is it?

Comment: It is sharepoint 2013.  Sorry I should have fleshed the question out more.  Once more the flipbooks load perfectly fine if you link to them or if you put them in an iframe outside of sharepoint.  Its just when I try to put them in a cewp/iframe/page viewer on a sharepoint page.  Also the flipbooks are hosted on the sharepoint IIS server.